# I dont know how to fix the Subquery returned more than 1 value in c#

Tags: c#, sql

*this error was shown in my summary.aspx.cs . I dont know how to fix it. It is new to me*

***Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. The statement has been terminated.***

**Here is my codes.**

```
public partial class Customer_Summary : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
    public static string seats;




double fare;
string fname, lname;
double totalfare;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Thesis;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            string getBusID = "Select Fare FROM trip WHERE Terminal = '" + (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["origin"] + "' AND Destination = '" + (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["destination"] + "'";
            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(getBusID, con);
            SqlDataReader reader2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader2.Read())
            {
                fare = (double)reader2.GetDecimal(0);
            }
            reader2.Close();

            string getname = "select fname,lname from customer where Email='" + (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["cusEmail"] + "'";
            SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand(getname, con);
            SqlDataReader reader3 = cmd3.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader3.Read())
            {
                fname = reader3.GetString(0);
                lname = reader3.GetString(1);
            }




        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            Console.Write(ex.Message.ToString());
            //lb_status.Text = ex.Message.ToString();
        }

        lb_destination.Text = (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["goingto"];
        lb_origin.Text = (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["origin"];
        totalfare = fare * Convert.ToDouble(HttpContext.Current.Session["numseatsfinal"]);
        lb_seat.Text = (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["seats"];
        lb_email.Text = (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["Email"];
        lb_fname.Text = (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["FName"];
        lb_lname.Text = (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["LName"];

        lb_fare.Text = fare.ToString() + " * " + Convert.ToString((double)HttpContext.Current.Session["numseatsfinal"]) + " =" + totalfare.ToString()  ;
        lb_fname.Text = fname;
        lb_lname.Text = lname;
    }

}
protected void bt_finalize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Thesis;Integrated Security=True"))
    { 
        try
        {
            con.Open();

            string CustomerID = "Select CustomerID FROM Customer WHERE CustomerID ='"+Session["CustomerID"]+ "'";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(CustomerID, con);
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.Read())
            {
                Session["CustomerID"] = reader.GetInt32(0);
            }
            reader.Close();

            string getBusID = "Select Fare FROM Trip WHERE TripID = '" + Session["TripID"] + "'";
            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(getBusID, con);
            SqlDataReader reader2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader2.Read())
            {
                fare = (double)reader2.GetDecimal(0);
            }
            reader2.Close();
            totalfare = fare * Convert.ToDouble(HttpContext.Current.Session["numseatsfinal"]);
            double totalPayment = 0.00;

            lb_status.Text = "Total Fare: " + totalfare.ToString();



            string add = "set identity_insert ticketing off;insert into ticketing(seat,customerID,tripID,reservationdate,fare) values('" + (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["seats"] + "',(select distinct customerID from customer where email = '" + (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["cusEmail"] + "'),(Select distinct tripID from trip where terminal = '" + (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["origin"] + "' and destination = '" + (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["destination"] + "'),GETDATE()," + totalfare + ")";

           SqlCommand addProd = new SqlCommand(add, con);


            addProd.ExecuteNonQuery();


            con.Close();
                Label5.Text = "Successfully Reserved!";

            bt_finalize.Enabled = false;

        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            Console.Write(ex.Message.ToString());
            lb_status.Text = ex.Message.ToString();
        }

    }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("/Customer/Seats.aspx");
    base.OnLoad(e);
}
}
```

Please help. Thank you

Here is an additional codes before the summary.aspx.cs
I wish you can find the error in here or any of them.

```
public partial class Customer_Seats : System.Web.UI.Page
{
private string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connString"].ConnectionString;
private static DataSet ds = new DataSet();

private CryptoLibrary nCl = new CryptoLibrary();

private static string password;
private static int AnnouncementId;

private static System.IO.Stream fs;
private static System.IO.BinaryReader br;
private static Byte[] bytes;
public static int numseats;
public static string origin;
public static string destination;
private void ListFields()
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        string cmdstr = "Select Seat FROM Ticketing";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdstr, connection);
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        adp.Fill(ds);


    }
}
protected void ShowIndividucalRecord(int Announcementid)
{
    SqlDataReader rdr = null;
    SqlConnection conn = null;
    SqlCommand selcmd = null;
    List<string> seats = new List<string>();


    {
        conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connString"].ConnectionString);
        selcmd = new SqlCommand("Select Seat FROM Ticketing WHERE TripID=" + Announcementid, conn);

        conn.Open();
        rdr = selcmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            if (rdr.GetString(0).Contains(','))
            {
                string[] token = rdr.GetString(0).Split(',');
                foreach (string seat in token)
                {
                    seats.Add(seat);
                }
            }
            else
                seats.Add(rdr.GetString(0));
        }
        foreach (string seat in seats)
        {
            if (seat == "s1")
                s1.ImageUrl = "~/Image/booked_seat_img.gif";
            else if (seat == "s2")
                s2.ImageUrl = "~/Image/booked_seat_img.gif";
            else if (seat == "s3")
                s3.ImageUrl = "~/Image/booked_seat_img.gif";
            else if (seat == "s4")
                s4.ImageUrl = "~/Image/booked_seat_img.gif";
            else if (seat == "s5")
                s5.ImageUrl = "~/Image/booked_seat_img.gif";
            else if (seat == "s6")
                s6.ImageUrl = "~/Image/booked_seat_img.gif";
            else if (seat == "s7")
                s7.ImageUrl = "~/Image/booked_seat_img.gif";
            else if (seat == "s8")
                s8.ImageUrl = "~/Image/booked_seat_img.gif";
            else if (seat == "s9")
                s9.ImageUrl = "~/Image/booked_seat_img.gif";
            else if (seat == "s10")
                s10.ImageUrl = "~/Image/booked_seat_img.gif";
            else if (seat == "s11")
                s11.ImageUrl = "~/Image/booked_seat_img.gif";
            else if (seat == "s12")
                s12.ImageUrl = "~/Image/booked_seat_img.gif";
            else if (seat == "s13")
                s13.ImageUrl = "~/Image/booked_seat_img.gif";
            else if (seat == "s14")
                s14.ImageUrl = "~/Image/booked_seat_img.gif";
            else if (seat == "s15")
                s15.ImageUrl = "~/Image/booked_seat_img.gif";
            else if (seat == "s16")
                s16.ImageUrl = "~/Image/booked_seat_img.gif";
            else if (seat == "s17")
                s17.ImageUrl = "~/Image/booked_seat_img.gif";
            else if (seat == "s18")
                s18.ImageUrl = "~/Image/booked_seat_img.gif";
            else if (seat == "s19")
                s19.ImageUrl = "~/Image/booked_seat_img.gif";
            else if (seat == "s20")
                s20.ImageUrl = "~/Image/booked_seat_img.gif";
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
}
protected void GetIndividualRecord(int Announcementid)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        string cmdstr = "Select Seat from Ticketing Where TripID =" + Announcementid;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdstr, connection);
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        adp.Fill(ds);
    }
}
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    numSeats.Text = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session["numseats"]).ToString();
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {

        ListFields();


        try
        {
            AnnouncementId = int.Parse(Context.Request.QueryString["TripID"].ToString());

            ShowIndividucalRecord(AnnouncementId);
        }
        catch
        {
            string source,
            message,
            back;
            source = "Admin Customer List";
            message = "You directly open the Admin Customer Update page without specifying a record.";
            back = "Please click the browser's back button to display the Admin Customer List.";


            Response.Redirect("/messages/generalerror.aspx?source=" + source + "&message=" + message + "&back=" + back);
        }
    }

}
protected void seatClick(ImageButton btn)
{

    //this.ibnext.Visible = true;
    if (btn.ImageUrl == "~/Image/available_seat_img.gif" && Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session["numseats"]) == 0)
    {
        this.seattable.Visible = true;
        btn.ImageUrl = "~/Image/available_seat_img.gif";


    }
    else if (btn.ImageUrl == "~/Image/selected_seat_img.gif")
    {
        this.seattable.Visible = true;
        btn.ImageUrl = "~/Image/available_seat_img.gif";
        if (this.txtseatnumber.Text.IndexOf(btn.ID.ToString() + ",") > -1)
        {
            this.txtseatnumber.Text = this.txtseatnumber.Text.Replace(btn.ID.ToString() + ",", "");
        }
        else
        {
            this.txtseatnumber.Text = this.txtseatnumber.Text.Replace(btn.ID.ToString(), "");
        }
        //numseats++;
        //numSeats.Text = numseats.ToString();
        HttpContext.Current.Session["numseats"] = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session["numseats"]) + 1;
        numSeats.Text = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session["numseats"]).ToString();


    }
    else if (btn.ImageUrl == "~/Image/available_seat_img.gif")
    {
        this.seattable.Visible = true;
        btn.ImageUrl = "~/Image/selected_seat_img.gif";
        if (this.txtseatnumber.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
        {
            this.txtseatnumber.Text = btn.ID.ToString();
        }
        else if (this.txtseatnumber.Text.Trim().EndsWith(","))
        {
            this.txtseatnumber.Text = this.txtseatnumber.Text + btn.ID.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            this.txtseatnumber.Text = this.txtseatnumber.Text + "," + btn.ID.ToString();
        }
        //numseats--;
        //numSeats.Text = numseats.ToString();
        HttpContext.Current.Session["numseats"] = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session["numseats"]) - 1;
        numSeats.Text = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session["numseats"]).ToString();
    }


}

protected void s1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    this.seatClick(this.s1);
}

protected void s2_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    this.seatClick(this.s2);
}

protected void s3_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    this.seatClick(this.s3);
}

protected void s4_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    this.seatClick(this.s4);
}

protected void s5_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    this.seatClick(this.s5);
}

protected void s6_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    this.seatClick(this.s6);
}

protected void s7_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    this.seatClick(this.s7);
}

protected void s8_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    this.seatClick(this.s8);
}

protected void s9_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    this.seatClick(this.s9);
}

protected void s10_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    this.seatClick(this.s10);
}

protected void s11_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    this.seatClick(this.s11);
}

protected void s12_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    this.seatClick(this.s12);
}

protected void s13_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    this.seatClick(this.s13);
}

protected void s14_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    this.seatClick(this.s14);
}

protected void s15_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    this.seatClick(this.s15);
}

protected void s16_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    this.seatClick(this.s16);
}

protected void s17_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    this.seatClick(this.s17);
}

protected void s18_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    this.seatClick(this.s18);
}

protected void s19_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    this.seatClick(this.s19);

}

protected void s20_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    this.seatClick(this.s20);
}



protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Summary.seats = txtseatnumber.Text;
    HttpContext.Current.Session["seats"] = txtseatnumber.Text;
    Response.Redirect("/Admin/TransSummary.aspx");
    base.OnLoad(e);
}

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("/Admin/TransSample.aspx");
    base.OnLoad(e);
}
}
```

Comment: in which line do you have this error?

Comment: on lb_status i guess. because it is where the subquery statement will show

Comment: Session["TripID"] whats the value in this

Comment: The TripID value is int.

Comment: @YogeshHShenoy I updated the data please check

Comment: Your error must be saying the line number in which the execution gets error. What is that line number?

Comment: There is no subquery in your text. Please only post the portion of code where the error occurs and tell us how we can reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
            string add = "set identity_insert ticketing off;insert into ticketing(seat,customerID,tripID,reservationdate,fare) values('" + (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["seats"] + "',(select distinct customerID from customer where email = '" + (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["cusEmail"] + "'),(Select distinct tripID from trip where terminal = '" + (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["origin"] + "' and destination = '" + (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["destination"] + "'),GETDATE()," + totalfare + ")";
```

There are subqueries inside the values that are going to be inserted.
"SELECT DISTINCT " can return more than 1 rows, so please make sure those subqueries return only 1 row.

Answer (score 0):

Also to add to what has been provided by other, you could safe guard your Subquery by using "TOP 1" to just get the first row.